# Cucumber/Capybara saves only .html screenshots without .png

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara

I'm trying to get .png or .jpg image screenshots after test failing. Unfortunately it saves only .html file.

**Rails 7.0.4**

**Ruby 3.2.0**.

**gem 'cucumber', '~> 8.0'**.

**gem 'capybara-screenshot', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.26'**.

env.rb file looks like below:

```
require 'simplecov'
require 'cucumber/rails'
require 'cucumber/rspec/doubles'
require 'capybara-screenshot/cucumber'
require 'email_spec/cucumber'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'database_cleaner/active_record'

World(FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods)

ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = false

begin
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
rescue NameError
  raise RuntimeError('You need to add database_cleaner to your Gemfile '\
                     '(in the :test group) if you wish to use it.')
end
Around do |_scenario, block|
  DatabaseCleaner.cleaning(&block)
end

Before do
  t = Time.local(2022, 5, 1, 10, 5, 0)
  Timecop.freeze(t)
end

After do
  Timecop.return
end

Cucumber::Rails::Database.javascript_strategy = :truncation

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome_headless do |app|
  browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new.tap do |opts|
    opts.args << '--window-size=1920,1080'
    opts.args << '--headless'
  end
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: browser_options)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless
Capybara.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
```

I was trying to change webdrivers but didn't work out, Selenium should work correctly. It's making screenshot of .html perfectly but couldnt get image/png. Gems updated to newest ones.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8I7j.png)

Comment: Are there any errors or warnings shown? Did you mean `env.rb` and not `.env` file?

Comment: Are you sure your tests are running with Selenium, and not rack-test?

Comment: @engineersmnky - no not at all, I can see my scenario with test that didn't pass and below I should see image screenshot and html - but I can see only html (I uploaded screenshot in description). Yeah you're right I meant env.rb file which is located in `features/support/env.rb`

@ThomasWalpole - yep, I'm sure tests should run using Selenium.

Comment: @bart_oz so please forgive my complete and utter ignorance here as I have never used this library however it appears that `:selenium_chrome_headless` is already a [registered driver](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/registrations/drivers.rb#L31) so your config is overwriting that. Is that your intention? Just trying to eliminate things that might interfere since Capybara::Screenshot also [registers](https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot/blob/6b80ac24fafa1e92052168807cc1dff2fa471af6/lib/capybara-screenshot.rb#L165) this driver as well

Comment: Also it may have something to do with the fact that the page can't render due to the `ActionView::Template::Error`, so it might not be able to take a screenshot of a page that it can't actually render visually but these are all just shots in the dark. I hoe you get it worked out.

Comment: @engineersmnky yep you're right but unfortunately changing config doesn't helped me. Still can't produce .png screenshots after fails even if it's issue with template error, just regular fail test. But thank you guys for engagement and trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found a solution to this issue. It looks like it was a problem due to webdrivers. What I did:

1. I Installed:

   `gem "webdrivers"`
2. In my cucumber config `features/support/env.rb` sets up:

   `Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless`

Now everything works.